Covariant derivative of Riemannian gradient along geodesic
I am trying to derive the covariant derivative of the Riemannian gradient of a smooth function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ along a geodesic $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$.
I have concluded that
$$
\frac{D}{dt} grad f(\gamma(t)) = \nabla_{\gamma^\prime(t)} grad f = Hess f(\gamma(t))[\gamma^\prime(t)],
$$
where $\nabla$ is the Riemannian connection. Now we go one step further
$$
\frac{D^2}{dt} grad f(\gamma(t)) = \frac{D}{dt} Hess f(\gamma(t))[\gamma^\prime(t)].
$$
Let $\nabla^3 f = \nabla^2 grad f$, how to interpret $\frac{D}{dt} Hess f(\gamma(t))[\gamma^\prime(t)]$ through $\nabla^3 f$?
